# Grouping lines with same leading word using Javascript Regex Engine

Tags: regex

Suppose you have the following multi-line string:

```
C1 10
C2 20
C3 30
C2 40
C4 50
C3 60
```

And you want to match only those lines which have the same leading word, so as to build the following result:

```
C1 10
C2 20 40
C3 30 60
C4 50
```

I am trying to figure out a solution with pure Regex, but I am stuck. Any help?

I did try what the regex that follows, but it didn't work...

```
Regex: /(^\w+\b)(.*$)([\s\S]*?\n)(\1)(.*$)/gm

Substitution:$1$2$5$3
```

Result:

```
C1 10
C2 20 40
C3 30

C4 50
C3 60
```

As you can see, it only works with the first occurrence, despite the fact that I have used a lazy quantifier in the third capturing group.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this using `reduce()`

```js
const data = `C1 10
C2 20
C3 30
C2 40
C4 50
C3 60`;

const result = data.split("\n").reduce((acc, val) => {
  const vals = val.split(" ");
  if (!acc[vals[0]]) acc[vals[0]] = vals[1];
  else acc[vals[0]] += ` ${vals[1]}`;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, axtck! But I am looking for a pure Regex solution. I used the javascript tag in order to point out the regex engine which I am working with. I will delete the javascript tag and add the regex engine to the title...